# HTML dynamic table not showing drop down button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table having a drop down on clicking dropdown is showing but there is no drop-down button on UI user have to click and check which has to drop down

[image: This is my image of html]

So how can I add that button on table cells?

Here is my code

```
<div id="tbl"></div>

    <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="link1">Report1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Link2">Report2</a></li>
    </ul>
     $(window).load(function() {
        $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
        $(".actionButton").click(function() {
          //get row ID

          //move dropdown menu
          $(this).after($dropdown);
          //update links

          $(this).dropdown();
        });
      });






    data1=[
           {
                "amount": 2808,
                "hour": "5",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 37923,
                "hour": "6",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 9052,
                "hour": "6",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 50527,
                "hour": "7",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 74615,
                "hour": "7",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 5426,
                "hour": "7",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 63324,
                "hour": "8",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 117544,
                "hour": "8",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 13468,
                "hour": "8",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 30209,
                "hour": "9",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 52757,
                "hour": "9",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 117462,
                "hour": "9",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 24549,
                "hour": "10",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 116078,
                "hour": "10",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 25947,
                "hour": "10",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 114416,
                "hour": "11",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 31145,
                "hour": "11",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 12485,
                "hour": "11",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 137941,
                "hour": "12",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 10133,
                "hour": "12",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 18576,
                "hour": "12",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 38092,
                "hour": "13",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 50742,
                "hour": "13",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 229840,
                "hour": "13",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 56461,
                "hour": "14",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 248120,
                "hour": "14",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 53381,
                "hour": "14",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 176758,
                "hour": "15",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 24684,
                "hour": "15",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 45027,
                "hour": "15",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 24637,
                "hour": "16",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 141824,
                "hour": "16",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 27328,
                "hour": "16",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 48356,
                "hour": "17",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 27359,
                "hour": "17",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 153281,
                "hour": "17",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 24531,
                "hour": "18",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 161967,
                "hour": "18",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 51463,
                "hour": "18",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 19577,
                "hour": "19",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 41405,
                "hour": "19",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 187858,
                "hour": "19",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 34996,
                "hour": "20",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 21356,
                "hour": "20",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 177706,
                "hour": "20",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 11272,
                "hour": "21",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 16796,
                "hour": "21",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 128191,
                "hour": "21",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 14767,
                "hour": "22",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 4424,
                "hour": "22",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              }
            ]
    data= [
           {
             "amount": 291589,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58337,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65970,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 296125,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 56545,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 72213,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 346605,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 62459,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65248,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 518212,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 104801,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 138151,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 628358,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 115223,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 134107,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 177866,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 66095,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 284069,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58789,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 67886,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 313128,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 59939,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 68558,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           }
         ]

         let formatData = function (data) {

                        let billdates = [];
                        let outlets = [];
                        data.forEach(element => {
                            if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                                billdates.push(element.billdate);
                            }
                            if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                                outlets.push(element.outlet);
                            }
                        });
                        return {
                            data: data,
                            billdates: billdates,
                            outlets: outlets,

                        };
                    };



                    let renderTable = function (data) {
                        billdates = data.billdates;
                        outlets = data.outlets;
                        data = data.data;
                        let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                        let table = document.createElement("table");
                        let thead = document.createElement("thead");
                        let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                        let th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = "Bill___Date";
                         th.classList.add("text-center");
                        headerRow.appendChild(th);
                        let grandTotal = 0;
                        let outletWiseTotal = {};
                        th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = "Total";
                        th.classList.add("text-center");
                        headerRow.appendChild(th);

                        outlets.forEach(element => {
                            th = document.createElement("th");
                            th.innerHTML = element;
                            th.classList.add("text-center");
                            headerRow.appendChild(th);
                            outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                            data.forEach(el => {
                                if (el.outlet == element) {
                                    outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                                }
                            });
                            grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
                        });

                      thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                        thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                        headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                        th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = "Total";
                       th.classList.add("text-center");

                        headerRow.appendChild(th);

                        outlets.forEach(element => {
                            th = document.createElement("th");
                            th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                             th.classList.add("text-right");   //ol totals
                            headerRow.appendChild(th);
                        });
                      /*  th = document.createElement("th");
                      a = document.createElement("a");
                      // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                      th.classList.add("text-center");
                      th.classList.add("dropdown");
                      a.classList.add("btn-default");
                      a.classList.add("actionButton");


                      // added
                      a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                      a.innerHTML = "Action drop";
                      th.appendChild(a); // added

                      headerRow.appendChild(th); */
                        th = document.createElement("th");
                        th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
                          th.classList.add("text-right");  // grand total
                  /*  console.log(grandTotal);*/
                       // headerRow.appendChild(th);
                    headerRow.insertBefore(th , headerRow.children[1] );
                        thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                        table.appendChild(thead);

                        let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");


                        billdates.forEach(element => {
                            let row = document.createElement("tr");  
                            td = document.createElement("td");
                            td.innerHTML = element;
                            row.appendChild(td);
                            let total = 0;
                            outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                                let el = 0;
                                data.forEach(d => {
                                    if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                                        total += parseInt(d.amount);
                                        el = d.amount;
                                    }
                                });
                               /*  td = document.createElement("td");
                                td.innerHTML = el; */



                               td = document.createElement("td");
                              a = document.createElement("a");
                              // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                              td.classList.add("text-right");
                              td.classList.add("dropdown");
                              a.classList.add("btn-default");
                              a.classList.add("actionButton");


                              // added
                              a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                              a.innerHTML = el;
                              td.appendChild(a); // added

                              row.appendChild(td);



                                 /* td.classList.add("text-right"); //oldata
                                row.appendChild(td); */
                            });
                            /*console.log("row is : " , row.children )*/
                            td = document.createElement("td");
                            td.innerHTML = total;
                             td.classList.add("text-right"); //column total
                           // row.appendChild(td);
                            row.insertBefore(td , row.children[1] );
                            tbody.appendChild(row);

                        });

                        table.appendChild(tbody);

                        tbl.innerHTML = "";
                        tbl.appendChild(table);
                        table.classList.add("table");
                        table.classList.add("table-striped");
                        table.classList.add("table-bordered");
                       table.classList.add("table-hover");
                    }
                     let formatedData = formatData(data);
                     renderTable(formatedData);
```

I have the drop-down to jayanagar malleshwaram and kolar which only shows link which is not good as user requirement; I want to show that as button. I am doing the right thing but don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle and share the link? will be easy to debug. Thanks.

Comment: @sridharreddy here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/xkt9501m/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class **btn** before you add **btn-default**

```
a.classList.add("btn");
a.classList.add("btn-default");
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
        $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
        $(".actionButton").click(function() {
          //get row ID
         
          //move dropdown menu
          $(this).after($dropdown);
          //update links
          
          $(this).dropdown();
        });
      });

   
    
    
    
    
    data1=[
           {
             "amount": 2808,
             "hour": "5",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 37923,
             "hour": "6",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 9052,
             "hour": "6",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 50527,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 74615,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 5426,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 63324,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 117544,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 13468,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 30209,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 52757,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 117462,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24549,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 116078,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 25947,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 114416,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 31145,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 12485,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 137941,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 10133,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 18576,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 38092,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 50742,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 229840,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 56461,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 248120,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 53381,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 176758,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24684,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 45027,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24637,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 141824,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 27328,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 48356,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 27359,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 153281,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24531,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 161967,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 51463,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 19577,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 41405,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 187858,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 34996,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 21356,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 177706,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 11272,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 16796,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 128191,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 14767,
             "hour": "22",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 4424,
             "hour": "22",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           }
         ]
    data= [
           {
             "amount": 291589,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58337,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65970,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 296125,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 56545,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 72213,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 346605,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 62459,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65248,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 518212,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 104801,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 138151,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 628358,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 115223,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 134107,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 177866,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 66095,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 284069,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58789,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 67886,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 313128,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 59939,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 68558,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           }
         ]

         let formatData = function (data) {

                      let billdates = [];
                      let outlets = [];
                      data.forEach(element => {
                          if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                              billdates.push(element.billdate);
                          }
                          if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                              outlets.push(element.outlet);
                          }
                      });
                      return {
                          data: data,
                          billdates: billdates,
                          outlets: outlets,
                          
                      };
                  };

           

                  let renderTable = function (data) {
                      billdates = data.billdates;
                      outlets = data.outlets;
                      data = data.data;
                      let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
                      let table = document.createElement("table");
                      let thead = document.createElement("thead");
                      let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                      let th = document.createElement("th");
                      th.innerHTML = "Bill___Date";
                         th.classList.add("text-center");
                      headerRow.appendChild(th);
                      let grandTotal = 0;
                      let outletWiseTotal = {};
                      th = document.createElement("th");
                      th.innerHTML = "Total";
                        th.classList.add("text-center");
                      headerRow.appendChild(th);
                      
                      outlets.forEach(element => {
                          th = document.createElement("th");
                          th.innerHTML = element;
                            th.classList.add("text-center");
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);
                          outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                          data.forEach(el => {
                              if (el.outlet == element) {
                                  outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                              }
                          });
                          grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
                      });
                    
                    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                      thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                      headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
                      th = document.createElement("th");
                      th.innerHTML = "Total";
                       th.classList.add("text-center");
                        
                      headerRow.appendChild(th);

                      outlets.forEach(element => {
                          th = document.createElement("th");
                          th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                             th.classList.add("text-right");   //ol totals
                          headerRow.appendChild(th);
                      });
                    /*  th = document.createElement("th");
                    a = document.createElement("a");
                    // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                    th.classList.add("text-center");
                    th.classList.add("dropdown");
                    a.classList.add("btn-default");
                    a.classList.add("actionButton");
                   

                    // added
                    a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    a.innerHTML = "Action drop";
                    th.appendChild(a); // added

                    headerRow.appendChild(th); */
                      th = document.createElement("th");
                      th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
                          th.classList.add("text-right");  // grand total
                  /*  console.log(grandTotal);*/
                     // headerRow.appendChild(th);
                    headerRow.insertBefore(th , headerRow.children[1] );
                      thead.appendChild(headerRow);
                      table.appendChild(thead);

                      let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

                      
                      billdates.forEach(element => {
                       let row = document.createElement("tr");  
                          td = document.createElement("td");
                          td.innerHTML = element;
                          row.appendChild(td);
                          let total = 0;
                          outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                              let el = 0;
                              data.forEach(d => {
                                  if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                                      total += parseInt(d.amount);
                                      el = d.amount;
                                  }
                              });
                             /*  td = document.createElement("td");
                              td.innerHTML = el; */
                              
                              
                              
                             td = document.createElement("td");
                             a = document.createElement("a");
                             // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                             td.classList.add("text-right");
                             td.classList.add("dropdown");
                              a.classList.add("btn");
                             a.classList.add("btn-default");
                             a.classList.add("actionButton");
                            

                             // added
                             a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                             a.innerHTML = el;
                             td.appendChild(a); // added

                             row.appendChild(td);
                              
                              
                              
                                 /* td.classList.add("text-right"); //oldata
                              row.appendChild(td); */
                          });
              /*console.log("row is : " , row.children )*/
                          td = document.createElement("td");
                          td.innerHTML = total;
                             td.classList.add("text-right"); //column total
                         // row.appendChild(td);
              row.insertBefore(td , row.children[1] );
                          tbody.appendChild(row);
                        
                      });
                    
                      table.appendChild(tbody);

                      tbl.innerHTML = "";
                      tbl.appendChild(table);
                      table.classList.add("table");
                      table.classList.add("table-striped");
                      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
                     table.classList.add("table-hover");
                  }
                     let formatedData = formatData(data);
                     renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
.btn {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tbl"></div>

    <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="link1">go to next</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Link2">next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey can i fix the width of the button because when some column has 0 some has 12345 some has 12345678 so the button size increasing or decreasing which is not looking good on UI

Comment: Check the snippet now. Give css of `min-width` to your `btn` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping something like this might help you.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
            $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
            $(".actionButton").click(function() {
                $(this).after($dropdown);          
                $(this).dropdown();
            });
        });
    
        data1=[
           {
             "amount": 2808,
             "hour": "5",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 37923,
             "hour": "6",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 9052,
             "hour": "6",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 50527,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 74615,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 5426,
             "hour": "7",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 63324,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 117544,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 13468,
             "hour": "8",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 30209,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 52757,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 117462,
             "hour": "9",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24549,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 116078,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 25947,
             "hour": "10",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 114416,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 31145,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 12485,
             "hour": "11",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 137941,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 10133,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 18576,
             "hour": "12",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 38092,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 50742,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 229840,
             "hour": "13",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 56461,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 248120,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 53381,
             "hour": "14",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 176758,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24684,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 45027,
             "hour": "15",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24637,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 141824,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 27328,
             "hour": "16",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 48356,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 27359,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 153281,
             "hour": "17",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 24531,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 161967,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 51463,
             "hour": "18",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 19577,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 41405,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 187858,
             "hour": "19",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 34996,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 21356,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 177706,
             "hour": "20",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 11272,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 16796,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 128191,
             "hour": "21",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 14767,
             "hour": "22",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 4424,
             "hour": "22",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           }
         ]
        data= [
           {
             "amount": 291589,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58337,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65970,
             "billdate": "2018-08-01",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 296125,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 56545,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 72213,
             "billdate": "2018-08-02",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 346605,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 62459,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 65248,
             "billdate": "2018-08-03",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 518212,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 104801,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 138151,
             "billdate": "2018-08-04",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 628358,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 115223,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 134107,
             "billdate": "2018-08-05",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 177866,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 66095,
             "billdate": "2018-08-06",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 284069,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 58789,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 67886,
             "billdate": "2018-08-07",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 313128,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
           },
           {
             "amount": 59939,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
           },
           {
             "amount": 68558,
             "billdate": "2018-08-08",
             "outlet": "KOLAR"
           }
         ]

        let formatData = function (data) {
            let billdates = [];
            let outlets = [];
            data.forEach(element => {
                if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                    billdates.push(element.billdate);
                }
                if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                    outlets.push(element.outlet);
                }
            });
            return {
                data: data,
                billdates: billdates,
                outlets: outlets,
                
            };
        };

        let renderTable = function (data) {
            billdates = data.billdates;
            outlets = data.outlets;
            data = data.data;
            let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
            let table = document.createElement("table");
            let thead = document.createElement("thead");
            let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
            let th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = "Bill___Date";
                th.classList.add("text-center");
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
            let grandTotal = 0;
            let outletWiseTotal = {};
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = "Total";
            th.classList.add("text-center");
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
            
            outlets.forEach(element => {
                th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = element;
                th.classList.add("text-center");
                headerRow.appendChild(th);
                outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
                data.forEach(el => {
                    if (el.outlet == element) {
                        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
                    }
                });
                grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
            });
                    
            thead.appendChild(headerRow);
            thead.appendChild(headerRow);
            headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = "Total";
            th.classList.add("text-center");
            
            headerRow.appendChild(th);

            outlets.forEach(element => {
                th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
                    th.classList.add("text-right");   //ol totals
                headerRow.appendChild(th);
            });
            th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
            th.classList.add("text-right");  
                    headerRow.insertBefore(th , headerRow.children[1] );
            thead.appendChild(headerRow);
            table.appendChild(thead);

            let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

            
            billdates.forEach(element => {
                let row = document.createElement("tr");  
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = element;
                row.appendChild(td);
                let total = 0;
                outlets.forEach(outlet => {
                    let el = 0;
                    data.forEach(d => {
                        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
                            total += parseInt(d.amount);
                            el = d.amount;
                        }
                    });
                    td = document.createElement("td");
                    a = document.createElement("a");
                    // th.innerHTML = "Action drop"; // removed
                    td.classList.add("text-right");
                    td.classList.add("dropdown");
                    a.classList.add("btn-default");
                    a.classList.add("actionButton");
                    

                    // added
                    a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    a.innerHTML = el;
                    td.appendChild(a); // added

                    row.appendChild(td);
                });
                /*console.log("row is : " , row.children )*/
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = total;
                    td.classList.add("text-right"); //column total
                // row.appendChild(td);
                row.insertBefore(td , row.children[1] );
                tbody.appendChild(row);
                
            });
                    
            table.appendChild(tbody);

            tbl.innerHTML = "";
            tbl.appendChild(table);
            table.classList.add("table");
            table.classList.add("table-striped");
            table.classList.add("table-bordered");
            table.classList.add("table-hover");
        }
        let formatedData = formatData(data);
        renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
.actionButton {
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: 5px;
    top: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <div id="tbl"></div>

    <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="link1">go to next</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Link2">next</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: hey...but still its showing dropdown on clicking   the data not that dropdown icon which you have added